# How does a word end up with two opposite meanings at the same time?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage

I'm thinking of the word Sanction. In the first example below it has the meaning of "to okay" or "to give the green light to", and is used as a verb.

In the second example it is a noun which has the meaning of "preventative measures" which although not a direct opposite meaning, comes close.

US sanctions the use of force against drug smugglers

US sanctions against drug smugglers appear to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I think if you look at the word as the decision process that got them to the approve or disapprove side of that coin, it clears things up a bit. 
US decides to use force against drug smugglers

US decision against drug smugglers appear to be working.
A sanction is just a popular opinion that some group of individuals decided on as the course of action they would take. When you look at it as the process it is the same, but if you only see the outcome of the vote, they appear to have opposite meanings.

Comment: Yeah, right....